# Uniqueness of a weak derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f\in \mathrm{L}^2[a,b]$. As usually $f'$ is the so called weak derivative of $f$ if $\forall \phi \in C_c^{\infty}(a,b)$ $\int_a^b f'\phi dt=-\int_a^bf \phi' dt$. Is it reasonably to think that $f'$ is unique, i.e. all weak derivatives of $f$ are equivalent. Could you help me to prove it?

Comment: It is unique up to a set of measure zero

Comment: Hint: You can approximate the characteristic function of any ball on the interior of $[a,b]$ with $C_c^\infty$ functions.  Use the Lebesgue differentiation theorem.  I would add more, but this looks like homework.  Tell me if it isn't.

Comment: We have proven it by using the [fundamental theorem of the calculus of variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations).